# HTML Input overflow adds padding (Firefox)

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

**EDIT: [Added Picture showing the left "padding"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaq9d.png)**

I am using HTML Input Element and also a Numeric Input Element.
On both elements.

When the number of chars is longer than the Input Element size and you are moving your cursor to the last entered char there is some magic "padding" added in the beginning of the Input Element.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Example:

```css
input{
  width:5em;
}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="000"><br>
<input type="text" value="000000000"><br>
<input type="number" value="000"><br>
<input type="number" value="000000000"><br>
```

**Note**

I'm using additionally a grid as background, but the grid won't fit if padding of the Element is changing.

Comment: this is unclear and don't make sense!

Comment: Added image to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right and you need to remove padding influence on your html blocks, you need to use

```
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Or apply this rule to needed block.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't do the trick.
I added an image showing my "problem"

Comment: Have you tried `padding:0` on those inputs ? I don't have such things on my side.

Comment: box-sizing:border-box; in combination with padding:0 helps! but there is still some small text indention (Currently using FF / Linux)

Comment: Unfortunately there are now support of padding negative values. And check border state. Turning it to `none` can save you additional px's.